# Visualizing protein-ligand interactions with LIGPLOT or any other suitable software?

Tags: software-recommendation, plot

I have used DOCK software to dock 10 ligands into the protein structure.

I want to generate a pdb file that contains all 10 binding modes of the ligands together with the protein. So all together in one pdb file.

Now, what I want to know is when I give this file to LIGPLOT, is it possible to generate something like:

```
%polar interactions XX  
%non-polar interactions XX  
%hydrogen interactions XX
```

Is there a way to do it with LIGPLOT, if now is there some other software that can be recommended for this type of assessment?

I have been having hard time, trying to find a way or software that can perform similar type of calculation and give me similar type of output that I want.

Best

Comment: You could also try asking at [Bioinformatics Q&A](https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/) if you don't get results here. I'm a user there, and they helped me after no one answer my question at Unix & Linux Q&A.

Comment: Oh I see, thanks I knew this is not the best place to ask this type of question but I didn't know where else.